# Netlogo - Stop simulation after a certain event

Tags: netlogo

I haven't as of yet seen this question on this website, so forgive me if it has already been answered.

I want my Netlogo simulation to stop after a certain event (In this case after all the black patches have been converted by turtles into yellow patches). How might I accomplish this? Here is my (basic) code so far:

```
  to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles amount [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks

end

to monitor
 show count patches
      show ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 360
    fd 1
    pen-down
    set color red


    if pcolor = black [
      set pcolor yellow

    ]  
  ]


  tick
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Put this at the very beginning of your `go` procedure:

```
if (all? patches [pcolor = yellow]) [stop]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `stop` but carefully!

The `stop` command only does the following:

1. Stops a *forever* button from executing
2. Ignores the rest of the commands **inside the current block**

Which means that it will not exit the current procedure or ignore the rest of `patches` or `turtles` in an `ask` command!

Example:

Code:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 4
end
to some-procedure
  let a 0
  ask turtles
  [
    show "Flag 1: before [stop]"
    set a a + 1
    if a > 2 [stop]
    show "Flag 2: after [stop]"
  ]
end
```

Output:

```
(turtle 0): "Flag 1: before [stop]"
(turtle 0): "Flag 2: after [stop]"
(turtle 1): "Flag 1: before [stop]"
(turtle 1): "Flag 2: after [stop]"
(turtle 3): "Flag 1: before [stop]"
(turtle 2): "Flag 1: before [stop]"
```

As you can see, the output contains 4 times `Flag 1` and 2 times `Flag 2`! Two of `Flag 2` were ignored by `stop` command, but all of 4 turtles printed `Flag 1`!

So, if you want to stop other turtles from executing the block, then you must put the `stop` command at very beginning! For example, the above `some-procedure` should be changed to something like this:

```
to some-procedure
let a 0
  ask turtles
  [
    set a a + 1
    if a > 2 [stop]
    show "Flag 1: before [stop]"
    show "Flag 2: after [stop]"
  ]
end
```

And then the output will contain only 2 times `Flag 1` and 2 times `Flag 2`:

```
(turtle 2): "Flag 1: before [stop]"
(turtle 2): "Flag 2: after [stop]"
(turtle 0): "Flag 1: before [stop]"
(turtle 0): "Flag 2: after [stop]"
```